# Indexing a list for value within certain range

Tags: python, list, loops

I have a list `x = [2, 3, 3, 4, 5]` and `y = [10, 40, 50, 9, 7]`. I want to print a list of indices for elements in `x` and `y` if `x <= 3` and `y => 30`. So in this case it would be the pairs `(3, 40)` and `(3, 50)`. Therefore I want a list of their indices as my output. So `result = [1, 2]`.

I tried writing a for loop as follows:

```
result = []
for i in x, y:
    if x <= 3 and y => 30:
        result.append(enumerate(i))
print(result)
```

Comment: `=>` isn't an operator in Python. Did you mean `>=`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension:

```
result=[i for i in range(len(x)) if x[i] >=3 and y[i]>=30]

print(result)

#[1, 2]
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this may be what you were aiming at:

```
>>> result = []
>>> xlist=[2,3,3,4,5]
>>> ylist=[10,40,50,9,7]
>>> for i, (x,y) in  enumerate(zip(xlist,ylist)):
        if x <= 3 and y >= 30:
            result.append(i)
>>> result
[1, 2]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to mention another way to achieve this using `np.where`:

```
import numpy as np

# need to convert x and y into array first
x = np.array([2, 3, 3, 4, 5])
y = np.array([10, 40, 50, 9, 7])

result = np.where((x >= 3) & (y >= 30))[0].tolist()

print(result)
```

Answer (score -1):

Assuming `x` and `y` are of the same length (otherwise you will have to check which one is shorter):

```
result=[]
for i in range(len(x)):
    if x[i] <= 3 and y[i] >= 30:
        result.append(i)

print(result)
```